# Send image and text in email from within app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

How can I send an image along with text, which is in the form of tabular data, in an email from within my app?

Please help and make suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

```
- (void)sendMailWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
if(mailController!=nil) {
mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[mailController addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"MyImageName"];
[mailController setSubject:yourSubject];
[mailController setMessageBody:yourBody isHTML:NO];
[self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
[mailController release];
}
else
{
//Do something like show an alert
}
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [`MessageComposer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MessageComposer/Introduction/Intro.html) sample App. Basically you use [`addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MFMailComposeViewController/addAttachmentData%3amimeType%3afileName%3a).

This is from the MessageComposer app:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rainy" ofType:@"jpg"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"rainy"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MFMailComposeViewController` from Apple to sent mail from iOS apps. Its official documentation is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html). Its usage

1. Add MessageUI.framework to your project
2. Import necessary header files

   ```
      #import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h> 
      #import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
   ```
3. To sent mail, open MFMailComposerController

   ```
   if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) { 
      MFMailComposeViewController *ctrller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; 
      ctrller.mailComposeDelegate = self; 
      [ctrller setSubject:@"Subject Goes Here."]; 
      [ctrller setMessageBody:@"Your message goes here." isHTML:NO]; 
      [self presentModalViewController:ctrller animated:YES]; 
      [ctrller release]; //if not using ARC
   } else { 
       NSLog(@Device is unable to send email in its current state.); 
   }
   ```
4. If you want to attach data you can use `addAttachmentData:` method

   ```
   [ctrller addAttachmentData:YOUR_DATA_IN_NSDATA_FORMAT 
              mimeType:YOUR_MIME_TYPE 
              fileName:YOUR_ATTACHEMENT_FILENAME];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can send image as attachment, use MFMailComposerController for sending mail.

```
-(void)displayComposerSheet 
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [picker setSubject:@"Test Subject"];
    // Attach an image to the email
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageName] ofType:@"png"];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [picker setMessageBody:body isHTML:NO];
    if (picker != nil)  {
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the [MFMailComposerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) class to allow the user to compose and send the mail. You can attach images and other files using the `addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:` method, and the body of the message (plain text or HTML) using the `setMessageBody:isHTML:` method.

Note that there is no way currently to include images in the HTML using `multipart/related`, you would have to either use [`data:` URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) (not supported by all clients) or images on an external server (also not supported by all clients, for privacy reasons). Or, of course, bypass Apple completely and send the mail via conversation with your own server.