# Sending Text and Image in one Email via ShareKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, sharekit

In iPhone App I want to send Image and Text together in single Email Using ShareKit

is it possible to do so?

If yes, How can it be done?

Comment: Possible repeat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716384/send-image-and-text-in-email-from-within-app

Comment: Here I want to know specific about ShareKit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ShareKit doesn't seem to have very comprehensive documentation, but from what I could find, it seems your best bet is to [share an image](http://www.getsharekit.com/docs/#image) and include your text as the title - as an e-mail, this *should* just work as 'sending an image with text'.

Comment: Actually I want to send Text in form of Tables which is having 10 Rows and 3 columns  along with image in a single Email is there any Way to do so?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be possible with ShareKit, you'd have to create an HTML e-mail by itself and I don't see that functionality in the documentation. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716384/send-image-and-text-in-email-from-within-app - you'll need to create the message body as your table.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I use:

```
 SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:myImg title:@"My Awesome Image!!!"];
    item.text = @"Look at this awesome Image";
    [SHKMail shareItem:item];
```

and it works well!